# SQL SERVER and Symfony SQLSTATE[28000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]

Tags: php, sql-server, symfony, odbc, sqlsrv

hey guys i need some help in am trying to connect mssql database to symfony and i get this exception every time i try to make a migrition

> An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT name, SCHEMA_NAME (uid) AS schema_name FROM sysobjects WHERE type =' U 'AND name! =' Sysdiagrams 'AND category! = 2 ORDER BY name':
> SQLSTATE [28000]: [Microsoft] [ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server] [SQL Server] Login failed for user 'sa'.

this is my .env file

```
DATABASE_URL="mssql://sa:sqlsql@TXS-PC\user:1433/COMPTA"
MSSQL_DATABASE_NAME="COMPTA"
MSSQL_DATABASE_HOST="TXS-PC\user"
MSSQL_DATABASE_USER="sa"
MSSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD="sqlsql"
MSSQL_DATABASE_PORT="1433"
```

and this is my doctrine.yaml file

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url:  '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
        driver:     sqlsrv
        host:   '%env(resolve:MSSQL_DATABASE_HOST)%'
        dbname: '%env(resolve:MSSQL_DATABASE_NAME)%'
        user:   '%env(resolve:MSSQL_DATABASE_USER)%'
        password: '%env(resolve:MSSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD)%'
        port:   '%env(resolve:MSSQL_DATABASE_PORT)%'
        server_version:     '14.0.17289.0'
       
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

Also, I added those extensions in my `php.ini`:

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_80_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_80_ts_x64.dll
mssql.textlimit = 2147483647
mssql.textsize = 2147483647
```

Also I instaled the MICROSOFT DRIVERS 5.9 FOR PHP FOR MICROSOFT SQL SERVER in the `ext` folder in XAMPP.

Comment: Probably the `sa` password is not correct. Note, that `mssql_textlimit` and `mssql.textsize` are settings for the old and unsupported `php_mssql` PHP extension.

Comment: no i checked the password and it's working so for the phpmssql do you have the new settings